# How to fuse 3 sub-vectors directly into 1

Tags: r, vector

```
geneOntology <- read.csv("IRE11_combind_E18_David_Direct_BP.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
genes <- geneOntology$Genes[geneOntology$Group == "E18>E11"]
genes
[1] "ERCC6L2, CDC14B, XRCC6, PRKDC, INO80, BCCIP, SPRTN, DMAP1, KIN, MUTYH, ERCC6, MDC1, ACTR5, POLM, HINFP, USP10, ACTR8, FANCG, RTEL1, SLX1B, EME2, NFRKB, LIG1, NEIL1, LIG3, PNKP, USP28, RPAIN, TDP2, ABL1, PARP2"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [2] "GTPBP4, WBSCR22, ERAL1, IPO9, BMS1, NVL, DROSHA, IPO4, TSR3, ZNHIT6, UTP14A, SETD4, FTSJ3, GNL3, DDX51"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
 [3] "RECQL4, SLX1B, EME2, LIG1, NFRKB, XRCC6, LIG3, INO80, KIN, RPAIN, ACTR5, POLM, ACTR8, RTEL1"
```

In this case the genes contains 3 sub-vectors. How to fuse the 3 sub-vectors directly into 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have right now is a vector of strings. Each of those strings is, itself, a comma-separated list of values. We can use `paste` with a "collapse" argument to combine all the strings into one, and then use `strsplit` to separate each comma-separated value.

```
genes <- c('x, y, z', 'a, b, c')
split.genes <- strsplit(paste(genes, collapse = ', '), split = ', ')[[1]]

genes
[1] "x, y, z" "a, b, c"

split.genes
[1] "x" "y" "z" "a" "b" "c"

split.genes[1]
[1] "x"
```

Answer (score 0):

These appear to be three separate comma-delimited strings in a character vector, so

```
genes <- paste(genes, collapse=", ")
```

should do it.  (In future, it would be helpful to provide the results of `str(genes)` as part of your question.)

Comment: Thank you. It get closer to the goal. But it put all the elements in the 1 subvector. I know I can name a new object and put the 1st subvector in. Is there any methods to directly fuse them?  To explain what I got: a <- paste(genes, collapse=", ") a[1] will give all the genes instead of single element. So I guess the genes still in the subvector

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want, but maybe `genes <- paste(genes, collapse=", ")` ?  Can you edit your question to show precisely what you want the output to be in this example?

Comment: @jdobres's solution works! I will try to make my questions more clear next time. Thank you all!